# Change all values of nested state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a component where it'll have a dozen nested values passed with a few parent props.

In this component, I have two buttons, each button has an onClick event, when pressed, I'm trying to have it so the values of the nested props are passed to a function and changed, and updated in the view.

For this example, I'll only pass someChildProp, here's an example prop:

```
List.defaultProps = {
  someChildProp: {
    field1: 1.4,
    field2: 1.2,
    field3: 1.6,
    field4: 1.1
  }
};
```

And when you press either button:

```
<a className="unit-selected" onClick={handleUnitClick('unit1')}>
  Unit 1
</a>
<span>/</span>
<a onClick={handleUnitClick('unit2')}>
  Unit 2
</a>
```

This will run handleUnitClick, which will check the value being passed and then run the function where I'd set all of the props.

```
  const handeUnitClick = (type) => {
    if (type === 'unit1') {
      convertProps();
    }
  }
  const convertProps = () => {
    Object.keys(someChildProp).map((item, index) => {
      // set new value with convertUnit(number)
      // concat to new object?
      // set state again?
    })
  }
  const convertUnit = (number) => {
    return number + 5;
  }
```

So setting a new state would look something like this in a .map.

```
  someChildProp: {
    key[index]: convertUnit(value)
  }
```

What I'm not sure what to do is how can I map through each, change the value, set the state of the entireChildProp?

So I'm stuck at this point:

```
  const convertProps = () => {
    Object.keys(someChildProp).map((item, index) => {
      // set new value with convertUnit(number)
      // concat to new object?
      // set state again?
    })
  }
```

How can I do this?

Here's the code altogether: https://codesandbox.io/embed/competent-firefly-soyv4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several details missing, but this roughly is what you were looking for being able to convert between two units?

A few notes:

- In this case, a `button` is probably what you want (instead of an anchor: `a`)
- For the onClick callback, you need to pass a function `() => this. handleUnitClick('unit1')`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      someChildProp: {
        field1: 1.4,
        field2: 1.2,
        field3: 1.6,
        field4: 1.1
      }
    };
  }

  handleUnitClick = type => {
    if (type === "unit1") {
      this.convertProps(this.convertUnitOne);
    } else if (type === "unit2") {
      this.convertProps(this.convertUnitTwo);
    }
  };

  convertProps = convertFn => {
    const someChildProp = {};

    Object.keys(this.state.someChildProp).forEach(item => {
      someChildProp[item] = convertFn(this.state.someChildProp[item]);
    });

    this.setState({ someChildProp });
  };

  convertUnitOne = number => {
    return number + 5;
  };

  convertUnitTwo = number => {
    return number / 5;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleUnitClick("unit1")}>Unit 1</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleUnitClick("unit2")}>Unit 2</button>
        <ul>
          <li>{this.state.someChildProp.field1}</li>
          <li>{this.state.someChildProp.field2}</li>
          <li>{this.state.someChildProp.field3}</li>
          <li>{this.state.someChildProp.field4}</li>
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Or, using hooks instead based off your Codesandbox.

The biggest problem is that you're using default props which you can't change (with the current setup). What seems like a better fit is state, or with hooks `useState` with the default value of the object (rather than the default props).

```js
const List = ({ someChildProp }) => {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    field1: 1.4,
    field2: 1.2,
    field3: 1.6,
    field4: 1.1
  })

  const handleUnitClick = type => {
    if (type === "unit1") {
      convertProps();
    }
  };

  const convertProps = () => {
    const newValues = {};

    Object.keys(values).forEach((key) => {
      newValues[key] = convertUnit(values[key])
    });

    setValues(newValues)
  };

  const convertUnit = number => {
    return number + 5;
  };

  return (
    <div className="modal-items">
      <header className="modal">
        <h3>List</h3>
      </header>
      <div className="unit-options">
        <a className="unit-selected" onClick={() => handleUnitClick("unit1")}>
          Unit 1
        </a>
        <span>/</span>
        <a onClick={() => handleUnitClick("unit2")}>Unit 2</a>
      </div>
      <div className="items-table-container">
        <div className="items-table items-performance">
          <h4 className="items-title">Performance</h4>
          <ul className="items">
            <li className="items-spec">
              <div className="items-spec-label">Field 1</div>
              <div className="items-spec-value">{values.field1}</div>
            </li>
            <li className="items-spec">
              <div className="items-spec-label">Field 2</div>
              <div className="items-spec-value">{values.field2}</div>
            </li>
            <li className="items-spec">
              <div className="items-spec-label">Field 3</div>
              <div className="items-spec-value">{values.field3}</div>
            </li>
            <li className="items-spec">
              <div className="items-spec-label">Field 4</div>
              <div className="items-spec-value">{values.field4}</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<List />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I'll try this out. I also updated with a codesandbox.

Comment: @kinx updated the answer with a second example based on what you provided

Comment: Thanks, I am a bit confused by your example. While I provided an example of what the data will look like, it will be passed via props, such as { someChildProp, someOtherChildProp }. That is where the data will come in.

Comment: I assume, instead of the example field properties, I'd do React.useState(someChildProp))?

Comment: Then you could either "copy" that on first render with `React.useState(props. someChildProp)` or you need to pass in a prop from the parent that allows updating that prop, for example `updateSomeChildProp` so that your `List` component can call that.